How to refresh data in a stateful widget triggered from another widget?
I'm currently trying my hand at my very first Flutter app and am still struggling to understand some concepts.
The main view of the app consists of a tab view.
Tab 'A' shows booked events.
The data is loaded from a Rest API (Future<List<EventInfo>>) and displayed using FutureBuilder.
In tab 'B', the user can search for events and ultimately book participation in an event via some child pages.
If the booking process is successful (i.e. the data could be sent to the API), I would like the application to activate tab 'A' on the one hand and to update the data there (reloaded from the API) on the other.
I have solved the switching from tab 'B' to tab 'A' with my own notfication class. This is dispatched when the booking is successful. (BookingSuccessfullNotification().dispatch(context);)
In the widget tree of the main view there is the following code
NotificationListener<BookingSuccessfullNotification>(
      onNotification: (notification) {
        // Show page of booked events
        tabController.index = 0;
        return true;
      },

However, it is not clear to me how I can get the widget, which represents tab 'A', to reload its data.
Just in case that matters: The app should run on Android and iOS. (no web)

Does this answer your question?

@Md.YeasinSheikh: Unfortunately not. In that question, widget 1 is the parent of widget 2.
In my case, widget 1 (on tab B) is a child of the TabView (widget 2), but I want to update widget 3 (on tab A) that has no direct relationship to widget 1.

Can you include a minimal full snippet that will reproduce the same error?

I have now found the following solution:
On the homepage, I have defined a variable in the state for the key of the booking overview on tab A:
Key bookedOverviewKey = UniqueKey();

I have extended the onNotification handler of the NotificationListener with a call to setState, which generates a new value for the key:
        setState(() {
          bookedOverviewKey = UniqueKey();
        });


I then passed the variable bookedOverviewKey as the value for the key parameter of the widget for tab A.
This seems to be working so far. However, I can't say whether this is a good solution ;-)
